# splice objects from arrays into new array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects which I would like to combine into a new array, splicing each object from one array into another based on the `previewNumber` value as the index used in `.splice`. I've used `.map` but it only loops for the length of `arrayOne`, below is some example code, any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    "title": "A Project",
    "slug": "a-project",
    "previewNumber": 2,
  },
  {
    "title": "New Project",
    "slug": "new-project",
    "previewNumber": 4,
  }
]

const arrayTwo = [
  {
    "title": "Project 5546",
    "slug": "project-5546",
  },
  {
    "title": "Project 456",
    "slug": "project-456",
  },
    {
    "title": "Rand Project 467",
    "slug": "rand-project-467",
  },
  {
    "title": "Random Project 245",
    "slug": "random-project-245",
  },
    {
    "title": "Example Project",
    "slug": "example-project",
  },
]


  const newArray = arrayOne.map((item) =>
    arrayTwo.splice(item.previewNumber, 0, item)
  );
  
  console.log(newArray)
  
  const desiredOutput = [
  {
    "title": "Project 5546",
    "slug": "project-5546",
  },
  {
    "title": "Project 456",
    "slug": "project-456",
  },
    {
    "title": "A Project",
    "slug": "a-project",
    "previewNumber": 2,
  },
    {
    "title": "Rand Project 467",
    "slug": "rand-project-467",
  },
  {
    "title": "Random Project 245",
    "slug": "random-project-245",
  },
    {
    "title": "New Project",
    "slug": "new-project",
    "previewNumber": 4,
  },
    {
    "title": "Example Project",
    "slug": "example-project",
  },
]
```

Comment: Just do `const mergedArr = [...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo]`. From the desired output, what I understood is that you are looking to merge both the arrays.

Comment: I realised I missed a key detail, I want to use the `previewNumber` value to splice the objects from `arrayOne` into the `arrayTwo` order but creating a new array rather than mutating `arrayTwo`

Comment: Is `arrayOne` sorted by `previewNumber`?

Comment: @LLawliet  no, I would like to use the value of `previewNumber` as the index in the new array when combining with `arrayTwo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `flatMap`. Here is an implementattion.

```js
const arrayOne = [ { "title": "A Project", "slug": "a-project", "previewNumber": 2, }, { "title": "New Project", "slug": "new-project", "previewNumber": 4, }];

const arrayTwo = [ { "title": "Project 5546", "slug": "project-5546", }, { "title": "Project 456", "slug": "project-456", }, { "title": "Rand Project 467", "slug": "rand-project-467", }, { "title": "Random Project 245", "slug": "random-project-245", }, { "title": "Example Project", "slug": "example-project", }];

const result = arrayTwo.flatMap((p,i)=>{
   position = arrayOne.find(k=>k.previewNumber===i);
   return position ? [position, p] : p
});

console.log(result);
```

Or you can convert the arrayOne to objects. Something like this:

```js
const arrayOne = [ { "title": "A Project", "slug": "a-project", "previewNumber": 2, }, { "title": "New Project", "slug": "new-project", "previewNumber": 4, }];

const mapped = Object.fromEntries(arrayOne.map(p=>[p.previewNumber,p]));

const arrayTwo = [ { "title": "Project 5546", "slug": "project-5546", }, { "title": "Project 456", "slug": "project-456", }, { "title": "Rand Project 467", "slug": "rand-project-467", }, { "title": "Random Project 245", "slug": "random-project-245", }, { "title": "Example Project", "slug": "example-project", }];

const result = arrayTwo.flatMap((p,i)=>mapped[i] ? [mapped[i], p] : p);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make the `newArray` copy of `arrayTwo`. After that, you could iterate through `arrayOne` add into `newArray` by splicing from `previewNumber + index`

```js
const newArray = [...arrayTwo]
arrayOne.forEach((el, index) => {
  newArray.splice(el.previewNumber + index, 0, el)
})

console.log(newArray)
```

**Full demo**

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    title: "A Project",
    slug: "a-project",
    previewNumber: 2,
  },
  {
    title: "New Project",
    slug: "new-project",
    previewNumber: 4,
  },
]

const arrayTwo = [
  {
    title: "Project 5546",
    slug: "project-5546",
  },
  {
    title: "Project 456",
    slug: "project-456",
  },
  {
    title: "Rand Project 467",
    slug: "rand-project-467",
  },
  {
    title: "Random Project 245",
    slug: "random-project-245",
  },
  {
    title: "Example Project",
    slug: "example-project",
  },
]

const newArray = [...arrayTwo]
arrayOne.forEach((el, index) => {
  newArray.splice(el.previewNumber + index, 0, el)
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: @gorak thanks for correcting. It is redundant to include a minus of one